# Get image names in html using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pick up image name in html using JavaScript? I searched google and there are some documents about how to get image name on `<img>` tag,

`var filename = tag.replace( /^.*?([^\/]+)\..+?$/, '$1' );`

But it return just one name of images. What I'm going to do is get all images name. Imagine the html below,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="imagebox">
            <img src="/some/path/imageOne.jpg">
            <img src="/some/path/imageTwo.jpg">
            <img src="/some/path/imageThree.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

after magic, return

`imageOne`, `imageTwo`, `imageThree`. How can I do this..?

Comment: Well... just iterate on img elements...

Comment: `after magic, return` - learn how to do magic :)

Comment: @Juntae why you added node.js tag ?

Comment: @hamism sorry because I will use this in node.js environment. actually what I'm going to do is compare really uploaded image or abandoned image, if the user upload image in editor, the server will save the image. and then display to editor wrapper img tag, but during write article, if the user delete image, the server won't recognize this image doesn't need, so I parse this and then if not in html tag, delete it

Comment: @Juntae what you want is *really* unclear

Comment: I just want to pick up image names. like Denys said, maybe I have to get img tags and then iterate to regex, Okay I understand if the environment is node.js, the question is different. because user couldn't use document.getBy.... sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Javascript code at the bottom of your html page :

**Solution for browser environment :**

```
var images  = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var images_urls = [];
var images_names = [];
var tmp;
for(var i=0;i < images.length;i++){
  images_urls[i] = images[i].getAttribute('src'); 
  tmp = images[i].getAttribute('src').split('/');
  images_names[i] = tmp[tmp.length -1].split['.'][0];
}

console.log(images_names); // ["imageOne", "imageTwo", "imageThree"]
```

and now `images_names` is an array containing the image names, in this case `imageOne`,`imageTwo` and `imageThree`

**Solution for Node.js environment:**

lets say you have images url stored in `images` variable like this :

```
var images = ["/some/path/imageOne.jpg", "/some/path/imageTwo.jpg", "/some/path/imageThree.jpg"];
```

you can use Regex, but in this case you can do it easily without using Regex, just split each image url and grab the last part of it, pretty simple, something like this :

```
var images_names = [];
var tmp
for(var i=0;i < images.length;i++){
  tmp = images[i].split('/');
  images_names[i] = tmp[tmp.length -1].split['.'][0];
}
console.log(images_names); // ["imageOne", "imageTwo", "imageThree"]
```

It is the same solution for both Browser and Node.js environment except for the way you get the elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will use split('.')[0]. I didn't intend to confuse you... Thanks.

Comment: @Juntae Good you know the trick, the solution in Node.js env is almost the samething.